# Close Safari popover using button click within popover

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I am working on a Safari extension which displays a popover on clicking the toolbar button.
I have added 2 buttons in the popover cancel and save. I want to dismiss the popover on clicking the buttons. How can I do this?

I tried using self.close() but once I click on any of the buttons, the popover closes but is not displayed again on clicking the toolbar. (The toolbar button does not register the click).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `safari.self.hide()` instead.

Comment: Me too, much appreciated! :)